How long does UK visa approval take?
As the consequence of the previous question, I applied for a new UK visa 2 weeks ago. I still haven't received any email about that. My previous visa was approved much quicker. The GWF track shows that my passport still hasn't reached VAC. What does that mean?
My educational trip to the UK will be on 17th of June so I am quite concerned since I am in Cyprus and it takes a week to send the passport back to me.

UK Visas and Immigration (UKVI) starts processing your application once you either:

verify your identity and submit your documents and application online using the UK Immigration: ID Check app.

Or

attend your appointment at a visa application centre (VAC) to provide your fingerprints and a photograph (biometric information)

The current processing time for Visitor visas is 3 weeks from the above start date, but can take longer if your application is not straightforward.
